# How can I query the db for all items in a table where a value meets one of the values in an array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably better explained with an example. I have a `documents` table that has a `country` attribute, for example `Document.first.country` could return `'DE'`. I have an array of country codes, for called `eu_countries` with the value `["AT", "BE", "BG", "CY", "CZ", "DE"...]` and I would like to query the db and return only documents that have a country code that is in the array.

Something with the same functionality as: Documents.where(country == "AT" or "BE" or "BG" or "CY" or "CZ" or "DE"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple

```
Document.where(country: eu_countries)
```

It is transferred to SQL similar to this:

```
select documents.* from documents where documents.country IN (values)
```